# How to keep vuepress source files in custom directory?

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I tried creating `./docs/ui/.vuepress/config.js` but it seems to be ignored.

The problem is I have more than one documentation platform. One is in `./docs/dev/` and the other (vuepress) will be in `./docs/ui/`

I did not see a way to change the source path.

This is my config file:

```
module.exports = {
    base: '/docs/ui/',
    dest: '/static/docs/ui',
    title: 'Hello VuePress',
    description: 'Just playing around'
}
```

I want to publish to `./static/docs/ui` when running `docs:build`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the people at VuePress say about [Directory Structure](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/directory-structure.html#directory-structure)

As far as "**Publishing**" goes, I had to add that functionality to the `scripts` object in `package.json`.

```
docs
├─ node_modules
├─ src
└─ package.json
```

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vuepress dev src",
    "build": "vuepress build src",
    "copy": "xcopy /E /I /Y \"src\\.vuepress\\dist\\\" \"c:\\publish\\directory\"",
    "postbuild": "npm run copy"
  },
  ...
}
```

You need to add a `copy` and `postbuild` property to `scripts` object that will copy the contents of the `dist` folder to a different location.

I'm using *Windows* hence all the fun escaping... The `copy` script issues the following command:
`xcopy /E /I /Y "src\.vuepress\dist" "c:\publish\directory"`
if that helps clarify what is happening.

If you are using Linux you might be using the `cp` command instead of `xcopy`